Derived exists by query causes an unintended flush of managed entity
I have the following code
    @Entity
    class Puppy {
        private Long id;
        private String collarName;
        private String collarId;
    }
    
    @Service
    class CollarService {
    
        private final PuppyService puppyService;
    
        @Transactional
        void updateCollar(Long puppyId, Collar changes) {
            // Do some stuff
            Puppy puppy = puppyService.getOne(puppyId);
            
            puppy.setCollarName(changes.getCollarName());
            puppy.setCollarId(changes.getCollarId());
            
            puppyService.update(puppyId, puppy);
        }
    }
    
    @Service
    class PuppyService {
        private final PuppyRepository repository;
        
        Puppy getOne(Long puppyId) {
            repository.findById(projectId).orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException(Puppy.class, puppyId));
        }
    
        @Transactional
        void updatePuppy(Long puppyId, Puppy updatedPuppy) {
            // Do some stuff
            Puppy databasePuppy = getOne(puppyId);
            
            if(repository.existsByCollarId(updatedPuppy.getCollarId())) {
                throw new PuppyCollarException();
            }
        
        // Do some stuff
    }
}

I expect, when this updateCollar method is called with a collarId which is already taken that I get PuppyCollarException thrown and I can then specifically handle that and translate it to a readable exception for the user.
What I instead get is a DataIntegrityViolationException which I don't want to translate to user and just show a generic error message.
I believe what happens is that the puppy object retrieved by the CollarService is a managed entity and when the existsByCollarId query is called it gets its changes somehow flushed.
I have managed to solve it temporarily by making the updatePuppy() method Transactional's propagation to REQUIRES_NEW
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
void updatePuppy(Long puppyId, Puppy updatedPuppy) {
    //...
}

And then the managed entity is not inside the same transaction and doesn't get flushed. Another solution might be just detaching CollarService puppy entity before passing it to the PuppyService.
But I am wondering why does this flush happen prematurely when just calling the derived exists by method of the PuppyRepository?
What would be the better solution here? I like the propagation solution better because it is simple, but this method is called in other Services not only in CollarService. And I am not sure what issues could arise. After some testing everything seems to be working correctly. Am I missing something under the hood be going with this solution?
It is a REST Web service Spring Boot, Hibernate, MSSQL application.

It happens because that is the default of HIbernate (or any ORM provider). Before executing a query it will flush the state as to have a consistent result from the query within the same transaction. If that wouldn't happen the newly available/modified data wouldn't be available (Hiberate/JPA is write behind, meaning the changes are only available in memory and not visible to the current transaction).

Thank you for the comment can you form it as an answer maybe with some links and I will accept it.
